# Sublime Text Interpreter does not work with GUI

Tags: python, sublimetext2, interpreter

I was using sublime text 2 to write some python code, and i configured to use the interpreter for python. So, i noticed that for simple code like this:

[image]

The interpreter works fine as you can see, after I press: `ctrl + B`

But, when i want to do the same with another that uses Gui code, it does not work, as you can see here:

[image]

What could be the problem? Am i missing something?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: As a test, you should install Anaconda and run the code there to see if you have any issues.

Comment: Just as a recommendation I was a sublime user and I still use it some times, but now VS Code is my personal option. Is really great give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SublimeText's default build systems [**suppress GUIs**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html?highlight=gui) in Windows.

You can use [**Console Exec**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Console%20Exec) or write a custom [**build system**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) to allow GUI execution.

Here's [**an example**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/template-multi-command-builds-with-input-powershell-script/18683) of a build system I developed for personal use.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i had some problems with my pc. This helped me a lot. I did not know about `Console Exec` . It is not the same, but it works. Thank you a lot.