# PyQt4 form ain't launching

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.4, qt-designer

I have made the following code to execute an form made in QtDesigner and converted to a '.py' file. My issue is that when i execute the code, it doesn't really show the form, but there is no message error and it appears an python icon on the toolbar like if it was running the form, i tried launching it from the cmd.exe, but the same stuff happens.PD: I use Sublime Text 3 and Python 3.4.4. Please help, thanks!

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import form3qt_edit

class Form3(QtGui.QMainWindow, form3qt_edit.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent =None):
        super(Form3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form3()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code from formqt3_edit.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(710, 450)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(-1.0)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:\'#effec7\';\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"\n"
""))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 391, 261))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color:\'#effec7\';\n"
"background-color: rgb(211, 207, 157);"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tP = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tP.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tP"))
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tP)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 151, 17))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.checkBox_2 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tP)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 141, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_2"))
        self.checkBox_3 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tP)
        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 141, 17))
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_3"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tP, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tC = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tC.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tC"))
        self.checkBox_4 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 141, 17))
        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_4"))
        self.checkBox_5 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 171, 17))
        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_5"))
        self.checkBox_6 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 261, 17))
        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_6"))
        self.checkBox_7 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 151, 17))
        self.checkBox_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_7"))
        self.checkBox_8 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 331, 17))
        self.checkBox_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_8"))
        self.checkBox_9 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 251, 17))
        self.checkBox_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_9"))
        self.checkBox_10 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 191, 17))
        self.checkBox_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_10"))
        self.checkBox_11 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 331, 17))
        self.checkBox_11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_11"))
        self.checkBox_12 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 231, 17))
        self.checkBox_12.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_12"))
        self.checkBox_13 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 201, 17))
        self.checkBox_13.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_13"))
        self.checkBox_14 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tC)
        self.checkBox_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 210, 231, 17))
        self.checkBox_14.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_14"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tC, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tO = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tO.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tO"))
        self.checkBox_15 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 141, 17))
        self.checkBox_15.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_15"))
        self.checkBox_16 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 201, 17))
        self.checkBox_16.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_16"))
        self.checkBox_17 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 201, 17))
        self.checkBox_17.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_17"))
        self.checkBox_18 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 191, 17))
        self.checkBox_18.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_18"))
        self.checkBox_19 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 221, 17))
        self.checkBox_19.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_19"))
        self.checkBox_20 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 161, 17))
        self.checkBox_20.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_20"))
        self.checkBox_21 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 271, 17))
        self.checkBox_21.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_21"))
        self.checkBox_22 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 201, 17))
        self.checkBox_22.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_22"))
        self.checkBox_23 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tO)
        self.checkBox_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 231, 17))
        self.checkBox_23.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_23"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tO, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tA = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tA.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tA"))
        self.checkBox_24 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tA)
        self.checkBox_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 171, 17))
        self.checkBox_24.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_24"))
        self.checkBox_25 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tA)
        self.checkBox_25.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 121, 17))
        self.checkBox_25.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_25"))
        self.checkBox_26 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tA)
        self.checkBox_26.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 111, 17))
        self.checkBox_26.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_26"))
        self.checkBox_27 = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.tA)
        self.checkBox_27.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 241, 17))
        self.checkBox_27.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox_27"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tA, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, -10, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Yu Gothic UI Semibold"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.plainTextEdit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 411, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Yu Gothic UI Semibold"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(font)
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: \'#effec7\'"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setBackgroundVisible(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 370, 141, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-radius:\'20px\';\n"
"background-color:\'#bea575\';\n"
"border-color:\'#e2d2ae\';\n"
""))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 710, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Form3-QtDesigner", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Gestión de trámites legales", None))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Realización de línea base y estudios técnicos", None))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Realización de diseños", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tP), _translate("MainWindow", "Planeación", None))
        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Localización y replanteo", None))
        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Adecuación de accesos o vías", None))
        self.checkBox_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Instalación de obras provisionales y/o definitivas", None))
        self.checkBox_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Explotación de préstamos", None))
        self.checkBox_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ejecución de tratamientos silviculturales y manejo de coberturas", None))
        self.checkBox_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Construcción de obras de protección y drenaje", None))
        self.checkBox_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Realización de trabajos preliminares", None))
        self.checkBox_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ejecución de cimentaciones, fundaciones, relleno y compactación", None))
        self.checkBox_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Levantamiento o instalación de estructuras.", None))
        self.checkBox_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Levantamiento o instalación de muros", None))
        self.checkBox_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Realización de acabados y obras exteriores", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tC), _translate("MainWindow", "Construcción", None))
        self.checkBox_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Realización de pruebas", None))
        self.checkBox_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Operación obra de infraestructura", None))
        self.checkBox_17.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reposición de elementos o tramos", None))
        self.checkBox_18.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reparación de elementos o tramos", None))
        self.checkBox_19.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Limpieza de las instalaciones y elementos", None))
        self.checkBox_20.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mejoramiento o ampliaciones", None))
        self.checkBox_21.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Limpieza final de la obra e instalaciones temporales", None))
        self.checkBox_22.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Control de emisiones y vertimientos", None))
        self.checkBox_23.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cobertura o reconformación final del sitio", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tO), _translate("MainWindow", "Operación", None))
        self.checkBox_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Desmantelamiento/demolición", None))
        self.checkBox_25.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Obras de urbanismo", None))
        self.checkBox_26.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Uso final del sitio", None))
        self.checkBox_27.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reactivación de un servicio o sistema natural", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tA), _translate("MainWindow", "Abandono", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selección de actividades", None))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(_translate("MainWindow", "Por favor, seleccione las actividades de ingeniería que se llevarán a cabo en el proyecto, de acuerdo con la fase del ciclo de vida.\n"
"Luego de la selección, haga clik en el botón \"Seleccionar impactos\"", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Seleccionar impactos", None))
```

Comment: Can you post code for form3qt_edit?

Comment: i think it wasn't a good idea, but there you go!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text Interpreter does not work with GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752753/sublime-text-interpreter-does-not-work-with-gui)

Comment: @Enteleform I don't think it is a duplicate I think the windows is so not opaque it is completely transparent.

Comment: @Dan-Dev: If you are using one of SublimeText's default build systems, any GUIs you try to load will be supressed.  You will likely have to create a custom build system which loads the GUI as a separate process.

Comment: @Enteleform but Sergio Andres Arboleda Zuluaga says "i tried launching it from the cmd.exe, but the same stuff happens".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(-1.0)
```

to

```
MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
```

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop
The valid range of opacity is from 1.0 (completely opaque) to 0.0 (completely transparent).

I tried your code on Ubuntu with Python 2.7.11+ and got the same result as you

> it doesn't really show the form, but there is no message error and it
>   appears an python icon on the toolbar like if it was running the form

but changing this one line fixed the problem

UPDATED: Just tried it on Windows 10, Python 3.4.4, PyQt4, Sublime build 3103. It works with the updated line of code, even from Sublime (using Ctrl + B), with the two files provided with just the one change.

Comment: @Sergio Andres Arboleda Zuluaga If it is fixed and there is nothing else to do with this question perhaps you could accept the answer :-)